# How to calculate the size of custom cells having stackview inside?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a requirement where I need to make a custom UiTableview cell. I have made it and it was working just fine as expected. But Now inside a cell, I have to show multiple records (depends on number on subject in which the student is enrolled). so I can simplify my question like this

**Case**
I have a list of students coming from server in which there is list of enrollment against each student. So I have to show each student and its multiple enrolled subjects.

**My Approach**
I have created cell with a UiTextLabel for showing name. And below That I have taken a Stackview vertically which will show the number of subjects. So I will be filling each students enrolled subjects inside this vertical stackview programmatically.

**Code**

```
 func createEnrollemtStackView(_ mEnrollment : EnrollmentServiceModel ) -> UIStackView {
    var enrolledIn = "Not enrolled"

    if(mEnrollment.GradeServiceModel != nil && mEnrollment.GradeServiceModel?.Name != nil && mEnrollment.GradeServiceModel?.Name != ""){
        let gradeName = (mEnrollment.GradeServiceModel?.Name)!
        let gradeSectionName = mEnrollment.GradeSectionName
        let batchName = mEnrollment.BatchServiceModel?.Name

        enrolledIn = "\(gradeName) - \(gradeSectionName!) (\(batchName))"

    }else{

        let batchName = mEnrollment.BatchServiceModel?.Name
        let className = mEnrollment.ClassServiceModel?.Name

        enrolledIn = "\(batchName) (\(className)) school"
    }


    let lblEnrolledIn = UILabel()
    lblEnrolledIn.text = "Enrolled in"
    lblEnrolledIn.textColor = UIColor(hex:"F48024")
    lblEnrolledIn.font = lblEnrolledIn.font.withSize(10)
    lblEnrolledIn.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10.0)

    let lblEnrolledStatus = UILabel()
    lblEnrolledStatus.text = "Enrolled Status"
    lblEnrolledStatus.textColor = UIColor(hex:"F48024")
    lblEnrolledStatus.font = lblEnrolledStatus.font.withSize(10)
    lblEnrolledStatus.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10.0)

    let tvEnrolledIn = UILabel()
    tvEnrolledIn.text = enrolledIn
    tvEnrolledIn.font = tvEnrolledIn.font.withSize(13)
    tvEnrolledIn.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    let tvEnrolledStatus = UILabel()
    tvEnrolledStatus.text = mEnrollment.EnrollmentStaus
    tvEnrolledStatus.font = tvEnrolledStatus.font.withSize(13)

    let stackViewHorizontal   = UIStackView()
    stackViewHorizontal.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    stackViewHorizontal.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    stackViewHorizontal.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.leading
    stackViewHorizontal.spacing = 5


    let enrollmentSV = UIStackView()
    enrollmentSV.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    enrollmentSV.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    enrollmentSV.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.leading
    enrollmentSV.spacing = 3
    enrollmentSV.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown


    enrollmentSV.addArrangedSubview(lblEnrolledIn)
    enrollmentSV.addArrangedSubview(tvEnrolledIn)


    enrollmentSV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    enrollmentSV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.leadingAnchor,constant:0)
    enrollmentSV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.trailingAnchor,constant:0)
    enrollmentSV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.topAnchor,constant:0)
    enrollmentSV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.bottomAnchor,constant:0)



    let statusSV = UIStackView()

    statusSV.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    statusSV.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    statusSV.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.leading
    statusSV.spacing = 3
    statusSV.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    //
    //
    statusSV.addArrangedSubview(lblEnrolledStatus)
    statusSV.addArrangedSubview(tvEnrolledStatus)



    statusSV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    statusSV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.leadingAnchor,constant:0)
    statusSV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.trailingAnchor,constant:0)
    statusSV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.topAnchor,constant:0)
    statusSV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewHorizontal.bottomAnchor,constant:0)



    stackViewHorizontal.addArrangedSubview(enrollmentSV)
    stackViewHorizontal.addArrangedSubview(statusSV)



    return stackViewHorizontal
}
```

I am calling this function from the following method

> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

This function is giving me 2 more horizontally align stackview which are verticall themselves and contain my enrollment data such as enrolled in and enrolled status.

the data is valid. But I am facing issues. These are as under.

1. How to calculate the Row height ??
2. Why My stackview that are programmatically added in the designed stackview has margin from the left?

Comment: I think you need one section for each student (number of student = number of section)
And number of item -> 1(student info) + number of subject enrolled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a mistakes in your code that you are adding `enrollmentSV` and `statusSV` in `stackViewHorizontal`:

```
    stackViewHorizontal.addArrangedSubview(enrollmentSV)
    stackViewHorizontal.addArrangedSubview(statusSV)
```

*So no need to sent constraint on `enrollmentSV` & `statusSV`. They will be automatically adjusted with `stackViewHorizontal`.*

---

**For row height you don't need to calculate size. Although Just assign the height `UITabelViewAutomaticDimension` as:**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

---

**But for this you should have top and bottom constraints attached to your cell. Follow below picture:**

Where stack is your `stackViewHorizontal` and its **top, bottom, leading and trailing** is attached to `UITableViewCell`.

Because of top and bottom constraint and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, these table cell will become **self-sizing**.

[image]

---

### **Update**

In case your stack in in view, inside the cell. Do not assign the height to view only `top, bottom, leading and trailing` w.r.t. to `ContentView`, it will be automatically fetched from inner stack's content:

[image]

Comment: but inside content view of cell there is a another UIView that has attached to content view. and inside that UiView I have stackview

Comment: That is fine @Androidteem, You take as many view you need. Just don't assign height and let the view define the size. I am uploading an image in few minute to understand it.

Comment: ok I got it. please tell me why my inside stackview is having margin from leading

Comment: Try removing the constraints of inner stack, and give color to label in stack to check if they are actually taking margin or it is due to `.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.leading` ?

Comment: yes I have checked in same way as u said before posting the question. but still no luck